# Conflicting limit answers using calculator and wolfram alpha

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha, calculator

I want to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{\tan(x) - \sin(x)}{(\sin(x))^3}$,

Calculator says it's 0 when substituted with 0.0000000001.

Wolfram Alpha says it's 1/2.

The Problem Set says the answer is 1/2.

I think I believe Wolfram Alpha more but I've been using the calculator method so I can answer stuff really fast (because it's for a board exam, shouldn't spend too much time deriving) is there a way for me to know?

Comment: If you want to do it by hand you can save some time by rewriting your expression as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sec x - 1}{\sin^2x}$.

Comment: Your calculator might have some strange way it evaluates operations. I would add more parenthesis to try and get the calculator to do what you want it to do rather than what it thinks you wants to see if it gets a different answer.

Comment: What did you DO with your calculator to get that?  The numerator and denominator are both approaching $0$; did you divide $0$ by $0$? If your calculator thinks $0/0=0$, don't believe it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom was right; 0.0000000001 is too small of a number. 0/0 is math error. using casio fx-991es plus

Comment: @MichaelHardy the calculator probably knows that $\sin(0.0000000001) \neq 0$.  However, it can't calculate $(0.5 + \epsilon) - 0.5$ accurately since it calculates $0.5 + \epsilon = 0.5$

Answer (score 27, accepted):

$0.0000000001$ is too small of a number: the calculator got such a small answer for the top that it assumed it was zero (since the values subtracted in the numerator were rounded to the same value). The bottom was non-zero, so there was no division by zero error.  Zero divided by anything non-zero is zero.

If you're going to use the calculator method, I would try with a bigger number.  I think $10^{-5} = 0.00001$ should be small enough to give you a good answer without causing you to run into this situation.

Comment: Up vote this nice answer. But personally i don't think calculator method can "give you a good answer" anyway. For example, a calculator would almost definitely lead you astray if you would try to find the "value" of $\zeta(1)$ with that. So I suggest you say "help you make a good guess" instead.

Comment: Even **0.001** will give you a nice answer. Checkout [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+%28tan%28x%29-sin%28x%29%29%2F%28sin%28x%29%29%5E3+for+x%3D0.001&x=0&y=0).

Comment: You can also substitute **1E-1000** and the answer will stay the same.

Comment: @Vim I think the calculator method can probably give you a "good enough" answer on an exam like OP's board exam, where time is apparently an issue.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oops!  Sorry I missed that line in op's post.

Comment: I don't think this answer is *quite* correct. A calculator that uses floating point numbers is unlikely to round a very small number to zero. My guess is that $\sin 0.0000000001$ and $\tan 0.0000000001$ are so close together that the calculator rounded the two numbers to *exactly* the same number, meaning that it subtracted two *identical* numbers, getting zero.

Comment: @TannerSwett that's what I meant by what I said; maybe I didn't word it clearly.

Answer (score 40):

As a rule of thumb, try express everything in term of either $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ to see whether there is any obvious cancellation. For this case, we have
$$\frac{\tan(x) - \sin(x)}{\sin(x)^3} = \frac{\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} - \sin(x)}{\sin (x)^3}
= \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)(1-\cos(x)^2)}
 = \frac{1}{\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}$$
you don't need any calculator to know the limit is $\frac12$.

Comment: You beat me to it! Cleanest approach.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do it by hand is to use Taylor Series.  For $x\to 0$, $\tan x = x+\frac 13x^3+o(x^3), \sin x = x - \frac 16x^3+o(x^3)$  So $$\frac {\tan x - \sin x}{\sin^3 x}= \frac {\frac12x^3+o(x^3)}{x^3}=\frac12+o(1)\to\frac12$$

Comment: A small nitpick: the symbol $\approx$ makes the expansion look sketchy and somewhat handwavy, which may confuse the reader or OP; while this is fully well-defined and a valid and rigorous statement ($\tan x = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + o(x^3)$).

Comment: @ClementC. +1. I'm always trying to use $\approx$ as little as possible because it looks flippant.

Comment: I'd say it's rather silly to say $\approx$ looks handwavy, it's so utterly clear from the context that it's shorthand for $\mathcal{O}$(whatever the degree of the next term would have been). Rigorous math doesn't equal notation-anal math...

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not just that $\tan x - \sin x$ is approaching zero rapidly;
the real problem is that as $x$ approaches zero,
$\tan x - \sin x$ approaches zero much more
rapidly than either $\tan x$ or $\sin x$,
because (as shown by Ross Millikan)
$\tan x - \sin x \approx \frac12 x^3$ but 
$\tan x \approx x + \frac13 x^3$ and $\sin x \approx x - \frac16 x^3.$
At some point, for very small $x$, $x^3$ is so much smaller than $x$
that $x + \frac13 x^3$ and $x - \frac16 x^3$ round to the same number
inside the calculator, 
with the result that $\tan x - \sin x$ is evaluated to $0$ exactly.
This is an extreme example of *cancellation error,*
a well-known bugaboo of numeric computing methods.

For example, Google says `(tan(0.0000001)-sin(0.0000001))/(sin(0.0000001))^3` is $0.5029258124$ but `(tan(0.00000001)-sin(0.00000001))/(sin(0.00000001))^3` is $0.$
Trying various other values of $x$ such as $0.001,$ $0.0001,$ $0.00001,$ and
$0.000001$ shows that the value calculated by Google actually starts
to diverge *away* from $\frac12$
(presumably due to cancellation error) for input much smaller than $x=0.0001$.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the standard limits 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{3},\ \text{and}\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{6},\ \ \ \ \text{and}\
\ \ \ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin x}=1
\end{equation*}
then, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin ^{3}x} &=&\lim_{x\rightarrow
0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^{3}}\cdot \left( \frac{x}{\sin x}\right) ^{3}= \\
&=&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\tan x-x}{x^{3}}+\frac{x-\sin x}{x^{3}}%
\right) \cdot \left( \frac{x}{\sin x}\right) ^{3} \\
&=&\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\right) \cdot \left( 1\right) ^{3} \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

tan(x) and sin(x) are equal numbers in a calculator for small enough x because the calculator does not represent enough digits.  Hence the numerator turns to 0.

In the Windows calculator, your example works fine, but:
sin(0.0000000000000001) = tan(0.0000000000000001) = 1.7453292519943295769236907684886e-18

The difference is in the mantissa (the first part), which cannot properly represent such tiny sines and tangents.  **It needs more digits because that's where the difference between sine and tangent show up with such tiny x.**  This would be important in any formula that relied on those functions with such tiny values -- the output of the formula would be junk.  After all, if sin(x) = tan(x) for every tiny number, well, now what?

Note that it will happily cube the sin, though.  1.7453292519943295769236907684886e-18 cubed is

5.3165769342077880959321527892834e-54

And 0 divided by that is still 0 (the original problem result).  Note sin cubed of a junk sin value (also equal to tan) is also meaningless.  It's the mantissa (the first part) not the exponent (the second part) that has strayed into meaninglessness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is rounding and precision. Assuming that we are using radians
$$
\sin(0.0000000001)\doteq0.0000000000999999999999999999998333333333
$$
and
$$
\tan(0.0000000001)\doteq0.0000000001000000000000000000003333333333
$$
both of which, when rounded to $20$ significant places are
$$
0.000000000100000000000000000000
$$
Thus, assuming the calculator has no more than $20$ significant digits, the difference computed by the calculator would be zero.

---

Since
$$
\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5+O(x^7)
$$
and
$$
\tan(x)=x+\frac13x^3+\frac2{15}x^5+O(x^7)
$$
we get
$$
\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin^3(x)}=\frac{\frac12x^3+\frac18x^5+O(x^7)}{x^3-\frac12x^5+\frac{13}{120}x^7+O(x^9)}=\frac12+\frac38x^2+O(x^4)
$$
Therefore, if the calculator had enough precision, it would have gotten
$$
\frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{\sin^3(x)}\doteq0.500000000000000000003750000000
$$
for $x=0.0000000001$.